# Binding entity framework query to Devexpress LookUpEdit and ComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, devexpress

I've a simple table with only one column `UrzadSkarbowyWojewodztwo` that I'm trying to attach `Entity Framework` query to ComboBoxEdit or LookUpEdit (preferably both for reference). Can somebody share a a way to do this considering that I don't want do it from GUI?

I tried multiple ways and it's simply failing every time. I'm sure I'm missing something...

```
using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        {
            IQueryable<UrzedySkarboweWojewodztwa> listaWojewodztw = from d in context.UrzedySkarboweWojewodztwas
                                                       select d;

            //lookUpEdit1.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", listaWojewodztw, "", true);
            lookUpEdit1.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", listaWojewodztw, "UrzadSkarbowyWojewodztwo", true);
            lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = listaWojewodztw.ToList();
            lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "UrzadSkarbowyWojewodztwo";
            lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "UrzadSkarbowyWojewodztwo";

            LookUpColumnInfo col = new LookUpColumnInfo("UrzadSkarbowyWojewodztwo", "Województwo", 100) { SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending };
            lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Add(col);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to bind Entity Framework list with DevExpress ComboBoxEdit one needs to create additional `partial` class which has the same name as the `object` we're trying to put into `ComboBoxEdit`. Into that class we need to put an override on the `ToString()` for value we want to display in the ComboBoxEdit for the user.

```
public partial class SzkolenieMiejsca : EntityObject {
    public override string ToString() {
        return _MiejsceSzkolenia;
    }
}
```

Then we simply assign objects to the `ComboBoxItemCollection` and Devexpress will do the rest.

```
 using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM))
        {
            IQueryable<SzkolenieMiejsca> listaMiejsc = from d in context.SzkolenieMiejscas
                                                                    select d;


            ComboBoxItemCollection collection = comboBox.Properties.Items;
            collection.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (var miejsce in listaMiejsc)
            {
                collection.Add(miejsce);
            }
            collection.EndUpdate();
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

LinqServerMode-based components support server-mode binding with the Entity Framework 4.0:

[Linq Server Mode and Entity Framework 4.0](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/garyshort/archive/2010/08/23/linq-server-mode-and-entity-framework-4-0-coming-in-v2010-vol-2.aspx).

It is possible to customize Entity DataContext in the required manner to use it as a queryable source of the LinqServerModeSource:

```
IQueryable<UrzedySkarboweWojewodztwa> listaWojewodztw = 
    from d in context.UrzedySkarboweWojewodztwas
    select d;

...

lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = new LinqServerModeSource() {
        ElementType = ...,
        KeyExpression = ...,
        QueryableSource = listaWojewodztw
    };

...
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer? I added column name as string to `KeyExpression` and removed `ElementType` (as it claims to be used for internal use only) and nothing happens.. Do I have to add something more for things to show up in GUI?

Comment: The code I suggested for server-mode purposes only. I suggest that you contact DX guys for more explanation.

Comment: I got an answer from DX that I cannot use LinqServerMode -> `Our LookUpEdit does not support Server Mode. Only GridLookUpEdit, SearchLookUpEdit and GridControl support this mode. So, you cannot use LinqServerModeSource as a LookUpEdit datasource.`